# Google Calendar API watch event

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

I can get a list of events from a public Google Calendar by calling this function on `DOMContentLoad`:

```
function fetchCalendar() {
    gapi.load("client", () => {
        gapi.client.init({
            "apiKey": <apiKey>,
            "discoveryDocs": <discoveryDocs>
        }).then(() => {
            return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                "calendarId": <calendarId>,
                "timeZone": <timeZone>,
                "singleEvents": true,
                "timeMin": <timeMin>,
                "orderBy": "startTime"
            });
        }).then((response) => {
            for (let i=0; i<response.result.items.length; i++) {
                console.log(response.result.items[i]);
            }
        }).catch((reason) => {
            console.error(reason);
        });
    });
}
```

I would like to be notified when the content of the given calendar changes (add, remove, edit). So far I have this function, but I get a **401 Invalid Credentials** error:

```
function watchCalendar() {
    gapi.load("client", () => {
        gapi.client.init({
            "apiKey": <apiKey>,
            "discoveryDocs": <discoveryDocs>
        }).then(() => {
            // it seems to fail after this point
            return gapi.client.calendar.events.watch({
                "calendarId": <calendarId>,
                "resource": {
                    "id": "42",
                    "type": "web_hook",
                    "address": "./app.html"
                }
            });
        }).then((response) => {
            // what to do here, if I can solve the error 401?
        }).catch((reason) => {
            console.error(reason);
        });
    });
}
```

As a workaround I could fetch the calendar at given intervals, but getting notified of changes would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

"Events: watch" of Calendar API is required to be requested with the POST method. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch) In this case, the access token is required to be used. In your showing script, only an API key is used. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.

The API key can retrieve public contents like `I can get a list of events from a public Google Calendar by calling this function`. But, the API key cannot be used for requesting with the POST method.

#### Pattern 1:

If you want to use your script by retrieving the access token, I thought that "[JavaScript quickstart for Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js)" of the official document might be useful.

The service account might be able to be also used for this situation. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/GetAccessTokenFromServiceAccount_js)

#### Pattern 2:

If you want to simply test the script using the access token, you can use the following modified script.

```js
gapi.auth.setToken({ access_token: "### your access token ###" });
gapi.client.init({
  discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"]
})
  .then(_ => {
    gapi.client.calendar.events.watch({
      "calendarId": "<calendarId>,",
      "resource": {
        "id": "###",
        "type": "web_hook",
        "address": "./app.html"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      }).catch((reason) => {
        console.error(reason);
      });
  });
```

#### Note:

- If you cannot use the access token, your workaround of `As a workaround I could fetch the calendar at given intervals,` might be useful.

#### Reference:

- [JavaScript quickstart for Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js)

Comment: It might be a lame question, since I am new to this area, but can I configure OAuth to authenticate in the background, without prompting the user? The calendar I want to fetch and get notified is set to public.

Comment: @Nekomajin42 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `It might be a lame question, since I am new to this area, but can I configure OAuth to authenticate in the background, without prompting the user? The calendar I want to fetch and get notified is set to public.`, I couldn't understand your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to resolve from your 1st question in order.

Comment: I have read the instructions you have linked, and _if_ I understand it correctly, OAuth would solve my problem, because it can fetch the access token. But that one raises another issue. I would not like to tie this feature to a login prompt. Since the calendar is publicly available (and I am the owner), I would like to query it seamlessly. That's why I asked it in my first comment. I might be wrong, though.